# asp:HyperLink shows without hyperlink

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code. The issue is that i see the text but no hyperlink. I should mention that I am using the Hyperlink control within . I don't want to user the NavigateUrl within asp:Hyperlink as I need to do some manipulation.

```
     <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkRpt" runat="server" Target="_blank" Click="lnk_Click">View Report</asp:HyperLink>



       public void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Response.Redirect("Report.aspx");
       }
```

Comment: any chance that you want to modify the **style** of the link so it **look** like a hyperlink?

Comment: Give it a "CssClass", create the class in your linked CSS file or add it into your "<head>", add the respective CSS properties to get desired look.

Comment: Can you post the image of hyperlink that you are seeing and what is expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LinkButton instead:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">View Report</asp:LinkButton>

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string pageurl = "Default.aspx";
        Response.Write("<script> window.open( '" + pageurl + "','_blank' ); </script>");
        Response.End();
    }
```